# What is purpose of assign value in the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, return

I'm a BEGINNER so try please explain with simple words.

[The source of my code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aoFu0PojPMsFB1XsogQ2tONl4AaxNJJQu_FR_wJKt-4/edit?usp=sharing)

What is the purpose of line 3 here:

```
function sumAndMultiply(a,b,c) { 

        var sumAndMultiplyArray = []
    
        aPlusB = sum(a, b)[0];   //line3
    
        var finalSum = sum(aPlusB, c)[0]; 
    
        sumAndMultiplyArray[0] = finalSum;

        return sumAndMultiplyArray;
    
        }
    sumAndMultiply(4,7,5);
```

Is it is wrong to make it like that:

```
function sumAndMultiply(a,b,c) { 

        var sumAndMultiplyArray = []
        
        var finalSum = sum(a, b, c)[0]; 
    
        sumAndMultiplyArray[0] = finalSum;

        return sumAndMultiplyArray;
    
        }
    sumAndMultiply(4,7,5);
```

Comment: It depends on how the `sum` function works. Can you include its source?

Comment: @FZs ADD the source.

Comment: I don't understand, the source code I provide, I copy it in the console and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The sum function just receive two parameters, the third parameter `c` will be ignored and won't be summed up.

EDIT:

The purpose of line three is to tell the computer to save the resulting value of calling function `sum` with params `a, b` into a new variable called finalSum. This can be achieve in one line, but you should know that ease of read is way more important than compact code.

Comment: Okay, now what is the purpose of **line 3** , I mean what we try to say to the computer here. explain in simple words, please.

Comment: Added to the response